# Magneto2.3-How to make product category mandatory in Magento 2

Tags: product, magento2.3, category, required

I am using `Magneto 2.3`.

I want the product category field mandatory.

See below my code:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
<div class="field">
                <label class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Category')) ?>:</label>
                <?php if ($product_hint_status && $helper->getProductHintCategory()) : ?>
                    <img src="<?= $block->escapeUrl($this->getViewFileUrl('Webkul_Marketplace::images/quest.png')); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($helper->getProductHintCategory()) ?>"/>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($helper->getIsAdminViewCategoryTree()) { ?>
                    <div data-bind="scope: 'sellerCategory'">
                        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                        {
                            "*": {
                                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                                    "components": {
                                        "sellerCategory": {
                                            "component": "Webkul_Marketplace/js/product/seller-category-tree",
                                            "template" : "Webkul_Marketplace/seller-category-tree",
                                            "filterOptions": true,
                                            "levelsVisibility": "1",
                                            "options": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getCategoriesTree()?>,
                                            "value": <?= /* @noEscape */ json_encode($data['product']['category_ids'])?>
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <div class="wk-field wk-category">
                        <div class="wk-for-validation">
                            <div id="wk-category-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("CATEGORIES")); ?></div>
                            <?php
                            $categories = $data['product']['category_ids'];
                            foreach ($categories as $value) { ?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="product[category_ids][]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($value); ?>" id="wk-cat-hide<?= $block->escapeHtml($value); ?>"/>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php
                            if ($helper->getAllowedCategoryIds()) {
                                $storeconfig_catids = explode(',', trim($helper->getAllowedCategoryIds()));
                                foreach ($storeconfig_catids as $storeconfig_catid) {
                                    $cat_model = $block->getCategory()->load($storeconfig_catid);
                                    if (isset($cat_model["entity_id"]) && $cat_model["entity_id"]) {
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="wk-cat-container">
                                            </span><span class="wk-foldersign"></span>
                                            <span class="wk-elements wk-cat-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($cat_model->getName()) ?></span>
                                            <?php
                                            if (in_array($cat_model["entity_id"], $categories)) {?>
                                                <input class="wk-elements" type="checkbox" name="product[category_ids][]" value=<?= $block->escapeHtml($cat_model['entity_id']) ?> checked />
                                                <?php
                                            } else { ?>
                                                <input class="wk-elements" type="checkbox" name="product[category_ids][]" value='<?= $block->escapeHtml($cat_model['entity_id']) ?>'/>
                                                <?php
                                            } ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                $count = 0;
                                $category_helper = $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category::class);
                                $category_model = $block->getCategory();
                                $_categories = $category_helper->getStoreCategories();
                                foreach ($_categories as $_category) {
                                    $count++;
                                    if (count($category_model->getAllChildren($category_model->load($_category['entity_id'])))-1 > 0) { ?>
                                        <div class="wk-cat-container" style="margin-left:0px;">
                                            <span class="wk-plus">
                                            </span><span class="wk-foldersign"></span>
                                            <span class="wk-elements wk-cat-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></span>
                                            <?php
                                            if (in_array($_category["entity_id"], $categories)) {?>
                                                <input class="wk-elements" type="checkbox" name="product[category_ids][]" value=<?= $block->escapeHtml($_category['entity_id']) ?> checked />
                                                <?php
                                            } else { ?>
                                                <input class="wk-elements" type="checkbox" name="product[category_ids][]" value='<?= $block->escapeHtml($_category['entity_id']) ?>'/>
                                                <?php
                                            } ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                    } else { ?>
                                        <div class="wk-cat-container">
                                            </span><span class="wk-foldersign"></span>
                                            <span class="wk-elements wk-cat-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></span>
                                            <?php
                                            if (in_array($_category["entity_id"], $categories)) {?>
                                                <input class="wk-elements" type="checkbox" name="product[category_ids][]" value=<?= $block->escapeHtml($_category['entity_id']) ?> checked />
                                                <?php
                                            } else { ?>
                                                <input class="wk-elements" type="checkbox" name="product[category_ids][]" value='<?= $block->escapeHtml($_category['entity_id']) ?>'/>
                                                <?php
                                            } ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                }
                            } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add required class to the field input

```
class="required-entry"
```

Or use data-validate attribute

```
data-validate='{"required":true}'
```

Comment: Hi MTP,  I tried but it’s not working

Answer (score 0):

change categories attribute

Values Required 'yes'

http://prntscr.com/thd07u

Comment: Hi Dipakk, I am using webkul marketplace extension so in vendor login I have categories option. Change categories attributes is only for admin.